# Finding a polynomial over a prime field without a root.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field with prime field $k$. Suppose $[K : k] =: N ∈ ℕ$. Can I use this fact to write down a non-constant polynomial over $k$ with no roots in $K$?

Comment: This seems overly loose.  Are there really no restrictions on the polynomial?  The constant polynomial $1$ has no roots over $K$.  So does any irreducible polynomial whose degree doesn’t divide into $N$.  I think you need to clarify what “write down a polynomial” really entails.

Comment: If $k$ is finite, certainly.

Comment: Ah yes, it has to be non-constant. What does "divide _into_ $N$" mean?

Comment: For $k=\Bbb F_p$ you can take trivially $1+\prod_{u\in K} (x-u)=x^{p^N}-x+1$. For $k=\Bbb Q$ this seems to lack the sensible share of information.

Comment: Does it work for algebraically closed fields?

Comment: In that case is $[K:k]$ finite ?

Comment: Yes. (Don't worry, I'm trying to arrive at a contradiction.)

Comment: No. Any polynomial over $k$ is also a polynomial over $K$, and therefore has roots in $K$ by virtue of $K$ being algebraically closed.

Comment: By the way, a theorem of Artin and Schreier says that if $K$ is algebraically closed, $k$ is a subfield, and $[K:k]$ is finite, then either 1) $k=K$, or 2) we are in characteristic zero, $[K:k]=2$ and $K=k(i)$ with $i^2=-1$.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that $k$ is a prime field and you are trying to arrive at a contradiction. Then you can do the following. If $k=\Bbb{F}_p$, follow Gae's trick. If $k=\Bbb{Q}$, then $x^{N+1}-2$ is irreducible by Eisenstein, so its roots are in an extension of degree $N+1$.